# Change session timeout on IIS Express?

Tags: iis, session-timeout, iis-express

I would like to test session timeout problems while using IIS Express but I can't figure out how to modify the Session State setting so I can change the Time-out for Cookie Settings.  Is this a modifiable setting?

Answer (score 16):

Try following

1.In the web application's web.config file set sessionState timeout something like below (it is in minutes)

> `<sessionState timeout="30" />`

2.Make sure that your application's app pool idle time out is greater than or equal to the timeout specified above (you can run the following command from the iisexpress installation folder)

> ```
> appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='YourAppPoolName'].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:30:00
> ```

Comment: web.config is ignored completely even on a normal IIS 7 install.  Instead there is a specific setting called Time-out in Cookie settings that has to be modified.  It is not part of the application pool but is part of the IIS Application for your project under Default Web Site

Comment: I confirmed vikomall answer above when running VS2012 / IIS. Shane's suggestion did not work. I had to modify the web.config.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem of Visual Studio closing after a short idle period during debugging of ASP.NET web sites and Azure cloud services. (And hopefully this comment will help the crawlers find this question. :))