# How to Set Session Timeout for IISExpress

Tags: iis-express, session-timeout

I have found a partial answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222419/5778421) But it mentions 'YourAppPoolName'  and I have no idea how to determine that for iisexpress where there is no management console available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change session timeout on IIS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219169/change-session-timeout-on-iis-express)

Answer (score 0):

[Jexus Manager](https://jexusmanager.com) is the console for IIS Express.

But IIS Express does not have application pools, so even if you set the second setting like that answer indicated, it won't be picked up.

To test out sessions, you'd better use full IIS.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a go.